# I want a tax amount of the employee by calculating employee amount in IT tax slab.I have attached my table description and table in the image file

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgc5a.png)

Emp tabel and ITSlab table is different.I want output for the Total tax amount.
Like if employee falls on 0-80 then no tax.If he falls on 80-100 then 0-80 no tax and 80-100 is 10 per like that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT E.EMPID,E.SALARY,T.TAXPERCENT
FROM EMP E
JOIN ITSLAB T ON S.SALARY BETWEEN T.FROM AND T.TO
```

Could you please try